# Pandas - Removing rows with nan or None values

Tags: pandas

I have a some data that was pre-populated from another system whose DataFrame looks as below:

```
id;value
101;Product_1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Product_2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, Product_3,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan, Product_4,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None
102;,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None
```

I am trying to clean this up such that I remove all values that have 2 or more commas (,)continuously that are blanks.

Expected Output:

```
id; value
101; Product_1, Product_2, Product_3, Product_4
102;
```

Using semi-colon (;) to identify separators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, import the data while specifying the separator as a semicolon.  Then you can run `str.replace()` to collapse the commas.  There are actually three kinds of replacements you want to perform.

1. Replace the null values (and blank spaces) with ', '
2. Replace sequences of commas with single ', '
3. To deal with empty cells, add a final `replace`.  I've specified it as leaving a blank '', but for many purposes it would more useful to replace it with `numpy.nan` instead.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(path, sep=';')
df['value'].str.replace(r'nan|None| ', '').str.replace(r'\,+', ', ').replace(', ', '')
```

4. You might find it useful to have lists instead of strings, in which case you can use:

```
df['value'].str.split(', ')
```